# Best way to quickly mark all lines as code in IDA?

Tags: ida, idc

I have a fairly large obfuscated program, and I need to mark all of the lines as code. I was able to do this in IDC by iterating through the lines and running `MakeCode`. It works for small amounts of code, but when I tried it on the entire program I waited for hours and nothing happened. Is there a more efficient way to mark every line as code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a range (or  everything: <kbd>Ctrl-PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>Alt-L</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-PgDn</kbd>)
2. Press <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Choose how you want your code converted

Comment: sorry, I tried this and IDA froze

Comment: try selecting smaller chunks (e.g. a single segment instead of all)